# While I am using the date picker function in innerhtml the date picker does not work

Tags: jquery, html

Html code:

```
var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml5 = "<From><INPUT Id=\"one\" CLASS=\"datepicker\" type=\"Text\" readonly=\"true\">";
td5.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g,count);

var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml6 = "<To><INPUT Id=\"two\" CLASS=\"datepicker\" type=\"Text\" readonly=\"true\">";
td6.innerHTML = strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g,count);
```

Here is the date picker function

```
$(function() {
   $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,     
      changeYear: true,
      depth: "year",
      showOn: 'both',      
      buttonImage:'../../resources/theme1/image/calendar.png',
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      disabled: true,
     });
});
```

Comment: Place your `datepicker` initialization after `innerHTML`

Comment: @ RayonDabre I did't understand could you please describe...

Comment: By the time you are initializing `('.datepicker').datepicker`, element is not there in the DOM hence you want to initialize this widget when you are done with the `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can store `datepicker` initialization object as a global variable and can use it later whenever new `datepicker` elements are appended.

Try this:

```js
//GLOBAL_INIT will hold the initialization in global context to be used later
var GLOBAL_INIT = {
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  depth: "year",
  showOn: 'both',
  buttonImage: '../../resources/theme1/image/calendar.png',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  disabled: true,
};


var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml5 = "<From><INPUT Id=\"one\" CLASS=\"datepicker\" type=\"Text\" readonly=\"true\">";
td5.innerHTML = strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g, count);

var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml6 = "<To><INPUT Id=\"two\" CLASS=\"datepicker\" type=\"Text\" readonly=\"true\">";
td6.innerHTML = strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g, count);
//Will initialize when elements are appended
$(strHtml5).datepicker(GLOBAL_INIT);
$(strHtml6).datepicker(GLOBAL_INIT);


//Will initialize `'.datepicker'` elements initially
$(function() {
  $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker(GLOBAL_INIT);
});
```

Comment: the same code i have applied but its gives same result..I have an add function clicking add button one new column created.

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre, i dont know how to fiddle i am new here,  my requirement is i have a table with header through inner html i field the table body with add function..in a table there have a two date picker, while i am calling add function the date picker are not working, i tried so many times but i cant able to resolve it...

Comment: var count="1";     
function addRow(in_tbl_name){
var tbody=document.getElementById(in_tbl_name); 
var row=document.createElement("TR");
var td5=document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml5="<From><INPUT Id=\"one\"CLASS=\"datepicker\"type=\"Text\"readonly=\"true\">";
td5.innerHTML=strHtml5.replace(/!count!/g, count);
var td6 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml6="<To><INPUT Id=\"two\"CLASS=\"datepicker\"type=\"Text\"readonly=\"true\">";
td6.innerHTML=strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g, count);
row.appendChild(td5);
row.appendChild(td6);
count=parseInt(count)+1;
tbody.appendChild(row);}

Comment: <table ID="in_tbl_name" border="1>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Rule Id </b></td>
 <td><b>Rule Details &</b></td>
 <td><b>Fixed</b></td>
 <td><b>Repeats</b></td>
 <td><b>From </b></td>
 <td><b>To</b></td>      
 </tr>
</table>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="Button" onClick="addRow('in_tbl_name')"VALUE="Add New"></td>
 </tr>

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre thank you so much sir..Now its working

Comment: Sir if you dont mind could i ask one more questation..??

Comment: Thank you Sir.. Facing the same problem with radio buttons..:(

Comment: here is the code..  $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input[type=radio][name=test]').click(function(){
                var related_class=$(this).val();
                $('.'+related_class).prop('disabled',false);
                $('input[type=radio][name=test]').not(':checked').each(function(){
                    var other_class=$(this).val();
                    $('.'+other_class).prop('disabled',true);
                });
            });
        });

Comment: var strHtml3 = "<Fixed> &nbsp &nbsp<INPUT TYPE=\"Radio\" NAME=\"test\" VALUE=\"radio1\">";
td3.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g,count);

var strHtml4 = "<Repeats><INPUT TYPE=\"Radio\" NAME=\"test\" VALUE=\"radio2\"><select><OPTION VALUE=\"1\">Weekly<OPTION VALUE=\"2\">Fortnightly<OPTION VALUE=\"3\">Monthly<OPTION VALUE=\"4\">Quarterly<OPTION VALUE=\"5\">Annually</SELECT>&nbsp &nbsp ";
td4.innerHTML = strHtml4.replace(/!count!/g,count);

Comment: Sir as you told me to ask that question in a separately, i did but did't get any proper answer, help me sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262253/enable-disable-on-action-of-radio-button-in-innerhtml

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre, i don't understand how could i replicate it on my code which you are mention in my another question,

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre, sir  could you please check this qquestion once...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452359/how-to-fill-particular-tds-with-dynamic-values