# How to fill particular td's with dynamic values

Tags: java, html, spring

I am sharing an image below that shows i have a list value for id, details,parameter,and values. I am able to fill in the id and details, but failed to fill parameter and value.

[image: i am shearing an image that shows i have a list value for id, details,parameter,values, i am able to fill the id & details, but failed to fill parameter & value.]

Below is the **java class** for creating a list which i passed to controller. I am getting the value but cant display in it in td:

```
public class CompArray {
   public ArrayList<Rules> a1= new ArrayList<Rules>();

public CompArray (){
        Rules rul = new Rules();
        rul.setId("1001");
        rul.setDetails("khagfkj");
        rul.setParameter("lsrkjglkrs");
        rul.setValue("lskdjfk");

    a1.add(rul);

 }
public ArrayList<Rules> getRules(){

    return a1;
}
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRules1(ModelMap model) {
CompArray obj1 = new CompArray();
model.addAttribute("listRule1", obj1.a1);
return "hello";
}
```

**html**

```
  <c:if test="${!empty listRule1}">
            <table  border ="2">
                <tr>
                    <th align="center"><b>Rule ID</b></th>
                    <th align="center"><b> Rule Details </b></th>
                    <th align="center"><b>Rule Type </b></th>
                    <th align="center"><b>Rule Validity </b></th>
                    <th align="center"><b>Parameter </b></th>
                    <th align="center"><b>Value</b></th>
                </tr>

   <c:forEach items="${listRule1}" var="obj1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${obj1.id}</td>
                        <td>${obj1.details}</td>
                        <td>${obj1.parameter}</td>
                        <td>${obj1.value}</td>

                    </tr>                           
                </c:forEach>

            </table></c:if>
```

Can anyone tell how this issue can be fixed?
Thank You So much in advance for yours suggestion and help.

Comment: Please I need  a help to do it, please help some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `not empty` inatead of `!empty` toverify the if condition like this:

```
  <c:if test="${ not empty listRule1}">
```

Comment: i did this, i got a value, but how do i place them in a exact td could you help me to do this

Comment: Try to add CompArray obj1 = new CompArray(); in List list = new ArrayList(); list.add(obj1 );
model.addAttribute("listRule1", list);